# Correct rsync statement

Tags: backup, rsync

On the site "https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/rsync/" there is the following recommendation for a complete system backup:

```
sudo rsync --delete --stats -PSvahHAXx --log-file=rsync.log --exclude='/media/*/**' \
  --exclude='/proc/**' --exclude='/sys/**' --exclude='/tmp/**' \
  --link-dest=/media/deinname/medium/backup/rsync-alt /boot / /home \
  /media/deinname/medium/backup/rsync
```

Unfortunately it seems to be impossible to copy this statement correctly into this question, I am sorry. It is probably a problem of the double stars. Nevertheless my questions will be understandable - hopefully.

My questions:

1. What is the difference between `--exclude='/proc/**'`
           and                   `--exclude='/proc'`    ?
2. Is `--exclude='/media/*/**'` really correct?

   What is the difference to `--exclude='/media/**'`